# SignalR setup when separating out data access layer

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-web-api

Current setup has a single `webapi` with controllers, services, SignalR Hubs/server, data entity models and view models (say `Project.Main`). The thought is to create a separate project (`Project.Data` - `webapi`) for Data entity model, view models and services.

`Project.Main` would reference `Project.Data` to access services. Now these services currently utilizes Server HubContext to send data to clients like:

```
var ChatCompanyHubContext = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<ChatCompanyHub>();
                ChatCompanyHubContext.Clients.Group("ChatCompanyHub-1").newMessage(msg, for_user);
```

1. How should this part of code be setup in `Project.Data` ?
2. Should SignalR be setup considering `Project.Data` as client?
3. What would happen when call is made to `Project.Data` function from `Project.Main` incase `Project.Data` is setup as SignalR client?

**Background:**

To utilize `Azure functions` and to keep debugging easy we thought of just calling a service function from `Azure functions` trigger action. This is why we need to separate out the data access layer into a separate project (`Project.Data`) which can be referenced by both the `Project.Main` and `Azure Functions` Project.